# Export Firebug Net Tab request?

Tags: firefox, firebug-lite

I want to save the sequence of events and loading of resources on the webpage. Is there any way to export net tab web requests on Firebug ?

Answer (score 2):

I found different ways to do this:

1. **Firebug** itself allows to copy the content on the net panel as an HTML table. The `copy/paste functions work` as usual. It is sufficient for exporting the summary shown in the net panel.
2. **HTTPFox** addon can do the same by using the `Copy All Rows` contex-menu option. This produces a tab separated format which works better with text editors.
3. **[NetExport](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/netexport/)** Firebug extension adds export function to the net panel in Firebug. The data can be exported in `HAR format` which is used other [tools](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-adopters/) or as `JSON` data. The `online HAR Viewer` allows to see the exported data as it was captured in Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

I found that Firefox has addon [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/), This allows many more functionalities to test HTTP web requests.

Please, Let us know if there are any more ways.